# How to find value at risk in r

Tags: r

I am trying to find the value at risk. I have done the following:-

```
x<- matrix (1:40, ncol = 4)
xapp <- apply(x, 2, quantile, probs = c(0.1,0.2,0.5))
```

It gives me the following output:-

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
10%  1.9 11.9 21.9 31.9
20%  2.8 12.8 22.8 32.8
50%  5.5 15.5 25.5 35.5
```

which is clearly wrong.

To find VaR, I need to order the data for each column. I.e

X1 < X2 < X3 < ... < X10

Then VaR@10% = X(0.1x10) = row 1 , VaR@20% = X(0.2x10) = row 2 , VaR@50% = X(0.5x10) = row 5

It should gives me the following output:-

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
10%    1   11   21   31
20%    2   12   22   32
50%    5   15   25   35
```

How should I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
apply(x, 2, quantile, probs = c(0.1,0.2,0.5), type=3)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# 10%    1   11   21   31
# 20%    2   12   22   32
# 50%    5   15   25   35
```

There are many differt ways to calcualte quantiles. Type 3 is "nearest even order statistic" The default is type 7. Read the `?quantile` help page for complete details. Perhaps there is a type that is closer to what you want.